# Using Syngergy, I cannot use mouse buttons unless I hold the 'alt' key

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-7, synergy

I hope someone can assist with this. I'm running Synergy 1.4.2. I have a Windows 7 machine that is acting as the server, and an Ubuntu 11.04 machine running as client. On the client machine, I cannot use the mouse buttons such as forward and back unless I hold the alt key down. I cannot seem to find any information on why this is, or how to change it. Is this even a Synergy issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. I'm unaware of any work arounds. These links may be helpful:

- [Back/Forward mouse buttons leave synthetic Alt down](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/2466)
- [Extra mouse buttons](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/68)
- [thumb mousebutton not detected](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/960)